# Replace multiple full stop

Tags: python, replace

In file:

```
Hello........girlllllllllll
W.o.W
```

I tried:

```
for line in file.split('\n'):
    line = re.sub('[.]+', ' ', line)
    line = re.sub('[.]', '', line)
    print line
```

The result showed:

```
 Hello girlllllllllll
 W o W
```

Is it possible to get the result as below?

```
 Hello girlllllllllll
 WoW
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: So what you want is to remove and standalone dots and replace multiple dots with a space?

Comment: What is the condition for space and no space?

Comment: Just to be sure, you are trying to apply different "rules" for each line, no?

Comment: Note: to iterate over the lines of the file, you probably just want `for line in file:`. Also, `file` is a builtin identifier referring to the type of file objects; you should probably pick a different name, to save possible headaches down the line.

Comment: @RicardoRodriguez no, I just wonder that is it possible to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this:

```
for line in file.split('\n'):
    # Replace multiple dots with space
    line = re.sub('\.\.+', ' ', line) 
    # Remove single dots
    line = re.sub('\.', '', line)
    print line
```

Answer (score 3):

```
x = file.read()
print re.sub(r'\.\.+', ' ', x).replace('.', '')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try these:

```
line = re.sub('\.(?!\.)', '', line)
line = re.sub('\.+', ' ', line)
```

1. Replace with nothing dots, that are not followed by a dot.
2. Replace multiple occurences of dots with spaces.

Answer (score 2):

```
line = re.sub(r'\.{2,}', ' ', line)
line = re.sub(r'\.{1}', '', line)
```

Comment: This will actually strip some characters.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well your question you'd like to have multiple dots replaced by a space but a single dot replaced by an empty string.

You should simply change the first rule  from `[.]+` to `[.]{2,}`. In this way the rules will match only if it finds two or more dots, leaving the single dot to be managed by the second rule.

```
for line in file.split('\n'):
    line = re.sub('[.]{2,}', ' ', line)
    line = re.sub('[.]', '', line)
    print line
```